# How to use Cocoapods through different projects and targets

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have an Xcode workspace with projects `A`, `B`, and `C`. Project `A` has targets `AA` and `AB`, projects `B` and `C` only have one target each (which is the name of the project).

How can I specify different pods for each of the targets, and some of pods common to several of them?

I tried something similar as shown [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target) but I get this error:

> "[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `inherit!' for #. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue."

I'm using *Cocoapods 0.39.0*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `def` for shared ones:

```
def import_shared_pods
    # Shared pods follow:
end


target 'Target' do
    platform :ios, '7.0'
    import_shared_pods

    # Target pods follow:
end
```

Reference:
https://www.natashatherobot.com/cocoapods-installing-same-pod-multiple-targets/